# Why does database add null values although I am providing data?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, model-view-controller

I am inserting data in the textbox1 and dropdown1 but the data is only saved in the query which is written at the second position"i.e in this case c_name". C_name is either empty or inserts null values.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into market (m_name) values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')";
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into city (c_name) values('" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "')";

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "-1")
    {
        Response.Write("Please select a city");
    }


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please use [Parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Comment: Add breakpoint and debug your values.

Comment: You set CommandText twice and executes it only once.

Comment: Your code is overwriting the command, the first one is never sent to the server. Not sure if that's your problem but at least it's a line of code that is thrown away and shouldn't be there. Or it should be executed if that's what you want.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes that is exactly the problem

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen what should I do. Please someone write a solution code to this. please

Comment: You should `ExecuteQuery` for each query you want to execute, not just the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after the first `cmd.CommandText` and then you have to do the same for your second `cmd.CommandText`, and both query will perform their actions.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "-1")
   {
       Response.Write("Please select a city");
       return; // Must return don't execute after 'if' part or use 'else' there
   }

   con.Open();
   MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   cmd.CommandText = "insert into market (m_name) values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')";

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // First insert executed here

   cmd.CommandText = "insert into city (c_name) values('" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "')";

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Second insert executed here
   con.Close();
}
```